# How to use discontinuous index to form a new list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

If I have a list for example

```
A = [0.54,13,18,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
```

and I want `A[0:1]` and `A[3:]` to form

`[0.54, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

I know if I want a continuous segment in a list , I can do by `list[start:end]`

but if I want to use several index range in a list but these segments are not continuous, Can I using

`list[ ? ]` to achieve?

it seems I can do by `A[range1] + A[range2]`

thanks

Comment: Please provide some examples.

Comment: Why do you want the `0.540000`?

Comment: @RyPeck because python will convert the float to this ..

Comment: It just seems like an unnecessary edit for your question, since your question is focusing on the lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this.

```
A = [0.54,13,18,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
ranges = [(1, 3), (5, 8), (11, 14)]
print ([item for start, end in ranges for item in A[start:end]])
```

**Output**

```
[13, 18, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `print([item for start, end in ranges for item in A[start:end]])`

Comment: @SzieberthAdam Thanks :) Didnt see the 3.x tag.

Answer (score 4):

`itertools` may help

```
from itertools import chain
A = [0.54,13,18,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
list(chain(A[1:4], A[5:7], A[8:10]))
[13, 18, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough... You are already doing this. Anything else just adds unnecessary fluff. Not sure if there are any performance gains to be had.

```
>>> A[2:4] + A[7:9]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
```

To get just one item... Splice just one into a list.

```
>>> A[2:4] + A[7:9] + A[3:3]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
```